# Moment Js Issue : isoWeekYear & isoWeek method behavior

Tags: javascript, momentjs

1. **I fetched the iso week from a date by using moment's isoWeek function.**

   moment(new Date(2015,11,28)).isoWeek() //output 53
2. **I fetched the iso week year from the same date by using moment's isoWeekYear function.**

   moment(new Date(2015,11,28)).isoWeekYear() //output 2015
3. **But when I gave the same outputs to the input of moment function it results a different date.**

   moment().isoWeek(53).isoWeekYear(2015).isoWeekday(0).toDate()   //output Dec 28 2014

For other dates it is working correctly. Is there anything that I am missing in my code or it is a bug with Moment ?

here is a demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ScorpioCo625/7foh07a9/) `console.log("Iso Week :",moment(new Date(2015,11,28)).isoWeek());
console.log("Iso Year :",moment(new Date(2015,11,28)).isoWeekYear());
console.log("Date :", moment().isoWeek(53).isoWeekYear(2015).isoWeekday(0).toDate());`

Comment: native date does not know anything about moment

Comment: why are you passing moment to native date?

Comment: Hi sunder I have added this just to convert the response that is time stamp to date format.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response

Comment: to do that do this   moment().isoWeek(53).isoWeekYear(2015).isoWeekday(1).toDate();

Comment: Thank you.. What about the issue that I am having you have any idea about that ?

Comment: hey that cannot be done like that.if you want to create a date using new Date() there are some certain formats like strings,and arrays are only should be passed.but moment is an object.native Date constructor does not know anything about moment.so you cannot do like that

Comment: moment returns correctly only a year has totally 54 weeks.how come moment(new Date(2015,11,28)).isoWeek()  this will give you 53?

Answer (score 4):

It might be the order you've given to the segments. 
This works:

```
moment().isoWeekYear(2015).isoWeekday(1).isoWeek(53).toDate());
```

Check this out from Moment.js docs.

> if you chain multiple actions to construct a date, you should start
>   from a year, then a month, then a day etc. Otherwise you may get
>   unexpected results, like when day=31 and current month has only 30
>   days (the same applies to native JavaScript Date manipulation), the
>   returned date will be 1st of the following month.

Also isoWeekDays go from 1 to 7. By setting 0 you were getting next week's Monday.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to understand one thing.in your first operation whats happening here is,

```
moment(new Date(2015,11,28)).isoWeek() //output 53
```

while creating date using new Date() you have passed 11 as month.so what will happen is while creating date month will get incremented by 1.so the date will be 2015-12-28.so the week number is 53.

so for the 3rd operation you have passed the same result.so moment returned the correct date.

in your case if you want to pass month subtract that by 1  in your 1st operation.

```
moment(new Date(2015,10,28)).isoWeek();
```

now you will get the correct answer

Comment: My point is... It does not work for the date 28th December 2015. It is returning 2014 date instead of returning date of 28th December 2015 (Which is 1st day of 53rd weak of year 2015).

Comment: @Scorpio Co. https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2033 it seems a bug in moment